# How to exploit XSS in the Accept-Language header

Tags: xss

I found a potential vulnerability on a website of a small local company in my town (I know them personally and of course I'll report it). However I thought it'd be a nice opportunity to learn and experiment a bit.

The website runs Wordpress including an [outdated plugin](https://wpvulndb.com/vulnerabilities/8173). Due to that outdated plugin there is supposed to be a XSS-vulnerability in the Accept-Language header.
It seems XSS in the Accept-Language header is common, however I can't seem to figure out how to exploit it.

I thought I'd just have to modify the HTTP-request and make the Accept-Language header Javascript code, e.g: `"><script>alert(0)</script>`.

However that didn't gave any result, I didn't got an alert box, nor did I saw a trace of the Javascript-code in the source.

So (**TL;DR**), how would I exploit a XSS-vulnerability when it's in the Accept-Language header, and what would be a realistic scenario in how this could be dangerous? Because unlike reflective XSS you can't include this in e.g mails for phishing/...

Comment: "Because unlike reflective XSS you can't include this in e.g mails for phishing" - You'd still call that reflected XSS since the site is reflecting part of the request. I think you may be able to weaponize it in conjunction with e.g. a caching plugin, but just like other header-based XSS it's not straightforward do use it on its own. You may want to have a look at our lots of other header-related XSS questions.

Comment: why would the page show the `Accept-Language` header in the HTML anyway? (most users wouldn't know what that stuff meant)